# Apache vHost mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a vHost in Apache and I want to rewrite all subdomains to the subdomain www.domain.tld where the tld-part should be the one, the user enters.

I already looked at the documentation of mod_rewrite, but at least I didn't understand :) I hope someone can exlain it to me.

The actual part in my vHost-Config ist the following,... but only matches the subdomain problem, but not the tld problem:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1domain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I don't understand the %1 before my domain...

Comment: Have you read *any* of the docs?

Comment: yes I actually did, now understandig the %1

rewriting should be 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? www.domain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]`

but this doesn't solve my problem at all... - I want to rewrite it for 4 domains, having another ending. 

Have I to write this for every Domain, or can I take this in one Rule,... and how? Didn't find anything :/

Comment: You have the same problem that >90% of people using this tag have, difficulty with regular expressions. I'm sure many never find their exact problem but the similarities are everywhere. Break down your problem into smaller pieces. You can capture the tld with `%` backreferences. Is `domain` always exactly the same? Capture that, too. Do you also need to handle no subdomain? (Probably.) It's possible in two lines; have another go. Also, big blocks of code should be edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(?:[^.]+\.)?(domain\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%1/$0 [R=301,L]
```

That redirects all requests where the subdomain isn't www, has 0 or 1 sudomain levels, domain is `domain` and has one level of tlds. If you also need, say `.co.uk`, it would need modification.